# How do I update an assembly and its dependent assemblies in MS-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

This is the situation:

I have a Trigger.dll and a Trigger.XmlSerializer.dll.

I use CREATE ASSEMBLY to register them in MSSQL.

Now, I have compiled new versions of both.

I want to use ALTER ASSEMBLY to update them, however you can only update one at a time.  If you try to update one that has a dependency, it complains.  What's the trick to doing this?

I don't want to drop and recreate as I have to then drop all the triggers, etc. and there is database downtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to the [microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917407) you can use it by trick.

Notes

- These steps upgrade or downgrade assembly A in the scenario that was described in the "How to upgrade or downgrade an assembly" section.
- This example assumes that the versions of the two assemblies are both 1.0.0.0 and the assemblies are both written in C#. When you follow these steps, you try to upgrade assembly A and assembly B to version 2.0.0.0.

To upgrade or downgrade assembly A, follow these steps.

1. Back up version 1.0.0.0 of assembly B to a folder.
2. Modify and then recompile assembly B to version 2.0.0.0.
3. Use the ALTER ASSEMBLY statement to upgrade assembly B in SQL Server 2005.
4. Modify and then recompile assembly A to version 2.0.0.0. When you do this, reference version 1.0.0.0 of assembly B from the backup that you made in step 1. To do this, use the Csc.exe compiler tool together with the /reference switch. For example, use the following command:
     csc /target:library /out:AssemblyA.dll AssemblyA.cs AssemblyInfo.cs /reference:"BackupFolder\AssemblyB.dll"
     Note To verify the version of assembly B in the metadata of assembly A, open assembly A by using the Ildasm.exe utility. Then, verify the metadata information for the referenced assembly under the MANIFEST section.
5. Use the ALTER ASSEMBLY statement to upgrade assembly A in SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1):

I fear dropping the table and re-creating it is the only way.

The main reason for this is that values stored in a type in an assembly, are unusable if you update the assembly to a new version.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1) Generally you can avoid dependencies by using ILMerge to embed and internalize them. So the alter assembly statement should be enough in most cases. Haven't tried that myself yet with SQLCLR but I would give it a go.

2) Perhaps XML serialization assemblies are not necessary? [This article suggests it is only necessary when calling external web services inside SQL Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlclr/archive/2005/07/25/vineet.aspx). In itself a questionable design unless you are one of those people who wants to host all your business services inside the MS SQL Server product, rather than just writing your own stand-alone services in Windows (much easier to install, manage and maintain), i.e. more n-Tier pattern than "data tier does everything" anti-pattern. As your DLL is called Triggers.dll it doesn't suggest it declares any types or is a web service proxy. If I missed some other reason to use XML serializers then fair enough, please elaborate on that out of interest.